# How do you make it so you have a background image which gets covered up by content on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to replicate what is done to the image in the background on this website http://www.vokal.io/ , where the image is covered by content when you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they've done is essentially apply a `background-image` to an element e.g. a `div` in CSS to which they've added content, then set `background-attachment: fixed`.

As the element scrolls the background will still remain relative to the browser.